# I am testing auditing in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, audit

So, I  testing MongoDB filtering commands and input my server

```
mongod --dbpath data/db 
--auth 
--setParameter 
auditAuthorizationSuccess=true 
--auditDestination file 
--auditFilter "{ atype: 'authCheck', 'param.command': { $in: [ 'find', 'insert', 'delete', 'update', 'findandmodify' ] } }" --auditFormat JSON --auditPath data/db/auditLog.json
```

Then I attempted to insert data into my Cars db, but it tells me I am unauthorized. When I don't run the audit command, it works fine and I can easily insert data.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figure it out. I just need to make myself an admin